# Firefox UI freezes when doing resize of window

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I see this on latest FF 20, and maybe 've seen it before. It's seen often, for about 20% of resize operations.

When i do resize of FF window border, i.e. make window smaller, or move/drag window to the right, i see strange freezes of FF UI.

- FF can be closed during these freezes by Alt+F4, so not 100% freeze, it's semi-freeze
- Menu items don't drop down during these.
- Cursor is shown as "Resize arrow" during these.
- Freeze lasts for 5-20 sec, after that menu becomes active

I posted comment to FF developers (via Help menu), no reply. Win7 x64 Basic

Answer (score 0):

Such issues often occur, because of damaged user profile. Use the [Reset Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems) option in `about:support` to fix such issues.

[image]

Comment: I can't accept,sorry. I have also WInXP with the same issue. Delete/reset profiles on 2 PCs? No, i have many settings, toolbar customized, add-ons...

Comment: make a backup of your current profile and test it. Now compare the pref files and copy the old settings back you need.

Comment: how to? Have u instruction WHAT FILES to copy back, where profiles are located etc. Anyway- can FF fix a bug?

Comment: I use WinMerge to compare the old and new profile folder. The settings are stored in the prefs.js.